# is it possible to make a lazy loading component in a non-lazy loading page in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i've tried many times to lazy load a component in non lazy loading  page but that gave me an error

***//app.module.ts***

```
import {LoginPage} from '../pages/login/login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},

  ]
})
```

***//login.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import {LoginFormComponent} from '../../components/login-form/login-form';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   LoginPage, 
   LoginFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
  ],

})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

*this give me an error*

```
please add a @pipe/@directive/@component annotation.
```

*and how can i make a lazy loading componant in non lazy loading page if its possible?*

Comment: are you sure `LoginPage` is not lazy loading page? why set `IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),`? and which is the non lazy loaded component?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular a component can only be registered with one module.

Remove `LoginPage` from `declarations[]`, `entryComponents[]`, and delete the import from your `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},

  ]
})
```